# How can I get an element with 2 buttons side by side?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I need to have a Monotouch.Dialog element with 2 buttons side by side using MvvmCross

Has anyone managed this?

I have this so far but know it's not going to work as I have no way of knowing which button was tapped:

```
public class DoubleButton : Element, IElementSizing{
    UIImage image1;
    UIImage image2;

    public DoubleButton (UIImage image1,UIImage image2, string caption): base(caption)
    {
        this.image1 = image1;
        this.image2 = image2;
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetCellImpl (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCellImpl (tv);
        cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

        var imageView1 = new UIImageView (image1);
        var imageView2 = new UIImageView (image2);

        cell.ContentView.Add (imageView1);
        cell.ContentView.Add (imageView2);
        return cell;
    }

    public float GetHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 80;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two buttons and two commands, then you can just add two buttons and two commands - then make the button's trigger the commands.

```
public class DoubleButton : Element, IElementSizing
{
   UIButton button1;
   UIButton button2;

   public ICommand Command1 { get;set; }
   public ICommand Command2 { get;set; }

   public DoubleButton (UIButton b1,UIButton b2, string caption): base(caption)
   {
       this.button1 = button1;
       this.button2 = button2;

       this.button1.TouchUpInside += (s,e) => { if (Command1 != null) Command1.Execute(null); };
       this.button2.TouchUpInside += (s,e) => { if (Command2 != null) Command2.Execute(null); };
   }

   // ....
```

Comment: My solution seems to be flawed as referencing the ICommand seems to call it :/ what is the best way of doing that?