# MonoDroid.Dialog DoubleButton cell

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a cell which has 2 buttons side by side.

I have done this in MT.D : [How can I get an element with 2 buttons side by side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550803/how-can-i-get-an-element-with-2-buttons-side-by-side)

I now need to do this for the droid version.

Looking at the source for ButtonElement in the MvvmCross code I can see that Element has consideration for 1 click event only.

What is the best way of going about this for MD.D? It looks completely different (obviously) to the touch counterpart.

I can create a layout that has the 2 buttons in but I have no way of hooking the buttons up to click events.

Here is the layout code (dialog_double_button.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button02" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="button 1">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button03" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="button 2">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my element looks like :

```
public class DoubleButton : Element, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public DoubleButton (): base("", "dialog_double_button")
    {

    }

    protected override View GetViewImpl (Context context, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = DroidResources.LoadButtonLayout(context, parent, LayoutName);

        if (view != null)
        {
            var buttons = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Layout.dialog_double_button);
        }


        return view;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (Click != null)
            Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        if (SelectedCommand != null)
        {
            // TODO should we have a SelectedCommandParameter here?
            if (SelectedCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                SelectedCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code with:

```
[Activity(Label = "Login")]
public class Login : MvxDialogActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Root = new RootElement{ 
            new Section{
                new DoubleButton()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I can see the layout is added to the UI but inside my elements c# code calling `var buttons = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Layout.dialog_double_button);` yields nothing - so I can't hook the click events up.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is wrong with layout?

Comment: @Babibu - updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`view.FindViewById` will only work if `view` its the parent of that buttons. In your case it is not, it's the parent of "LinearLayout02", so you should get it first and use `FindViewById` on it.

(OP amending this answer as it was nearly what I ended up with)

I actually fixed it using:

```
var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(context.Resources.GetIdentifier("Button02", "id", context.PackageName));
var button2 = view.FindViewById<Button>(context.Resources.GetIdentifier("Button03", "id", context.PackageName));
```